# Why is docker-compose not building the containers in the correct order?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

This is docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  creator:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.php
    image: creator_image
    container_name: creator_container
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./config/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini

  artisan:
    image: creator_image
    command: sh -c 'php artisan optimize && php artisan config:cache && php artisan
      view:cache && php artisan view:clear && php artisan config:cache'
    container_name: creator_container_artisan
    depends_on:
      - creator

  cron:
    image: creator_image
    command: sh -c '(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "* * * * * cd /var/www && php
      artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1")| crontab - && /usr/sbin/crond
      start -f'
    container_name: cronjobs_container
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./config/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
    depends_on:
      - creator

  webserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
    image: nginx_image
    container_name: nginx_container
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"

    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/logs:/var/logs
```

Docker build will fail and will give the following error

`pull access denied for creator_image, repository does not exist or may require ‘docker login’`

The docker-compose above builds Laravel container and Nginx and also clears some Laravel cache and recreates it, as well as runs Laravel cronjobs.

That build fails when doing `docker-compose up --build` because Docker tries to run `artisan` container before `creator`

The only way to fix this is to comment out `artisan` and `cron` containers and read them after the build is done. How to fix this? `depends_on` isn't fixing that.

It doesn't matter how many `depends_on` I add, apparently [it's deprecated](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/issues/273), is there any way to force Docker to build the containers in the correct order?

Comment: `docker-compose build && docker-compose up`?

Comment: @super that fixed the problem! I didn't expect that honestly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compose doesn't have any notion of build order or build dependencies.

On the other hand, rebuilding an identical image is all but free: Docker can detect that you're running the exact same commands on the exact same input files and skip doing any actual work.  If you have the same `build:` block in all three containers, Compose will "build" the image three times, but two of them will use the Docker build cache, and in the end you'll have a single image with three names.

If you clean this up by having every container `build:` the (same) image; removing the `container_name:` and `image:` options (Compose generates reasonable defaults for these); removing `depends_on:` (the containers don't obviously make network connections to each other); and removing the `volumes:` mounts (the code should be `COPY`ed into the image); then this reduces to

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  creator:
    build: .
    restart: always

  artisan:
    build: .
    command: sh -c 'php artisan optimize && php artisan config:cache && php artisan
      view:cache && php artisan view:clear && php artisan config:cache'

  cron:
    build: .
    command: sh -c '(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "* * * * * cd /var/www && php
      artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1")| crontab - && /usr/sbin/crond
      start -f'
    restart: always
```

Comment: Should the volumes really be removed? The PHP files might be edited after the container starts, so the PHP files must be updated automatically on save

Comment: I didn't know that docker skips the build if the files are identical, thank you for pointing that out